# Commands are dropping characters after pressing enter in rescue mode terminal

Tags: command-line

I am having an issue with my graphic card, but that is not the subject of this question. I booted into rescue mode in an attempt to fix my issue, but I am experiencing something I have not seen in my 20 plus years of using Linux. I am using Ubuntu 23.04. After an upgrade shortly after installing 230.04, I started logging into a black screen. That is the subject of my other post, but is mentioned here, in case someone think that two may be related.

I am booted into rescue mode and have a command prompt for the root user. When I tyupe a command, all of the characters are typed out as expected, but when I press enter, some of the characters are dropped. The characters being dropped are not the same characters each time enter is pressed for the same command. Below is an example of what I am getting.

`sudo apt update`

uoatpdt: command not found

`sudo apt update`

nidia-mipig: command not found

`sudo apt update`

Command `sd` not found, but can be installed with: `apt install sd`.

`sudo apt update`

u: command not found

`sudo apt update`

so: command not found

As can be seen, there is no rhyme or reason for the characters being dropped. I am not able to follow the instructions for repairing the graphic drivers because the commands are not being executed as type.

Sometimes characters are not dropped, but are re-arranged.

`exit`

Command 'xtei' not found, did you mean:
command `xtel` from deb xtel (3.3.0-26
command `xte` from deb xautomation (1.09-4)
Try: apt install deb name.

What is odd is during the last two weeks I have been having this issue, once I was able to switch to the terminal mode from the login in prompt and purge nvidia* as instructed and when I attempted to install the nuveau driver, I got a message that it is already the newest package. I was also able to upgrade all outstanding upgrades while logged in to the terminal screen. Most of the time that I press ctl+alt+f2 through f9, nothing happens. I am not changed to the terminal screen selected. But, I still am not able to login in without going to a black screen. I am not sure if the two issues are related, but I do not think they are.

Any ideas for direction is appreciated.

Computer: System 76 Bonobo Extreme, 32 Gigs RAM